# Given X,Y sets with at least 2 elements, ¿is there an injective function f:X∪Y →XxY?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I started this exercise by cases; 
1) X∩Y=∅
2) X∪Y≠∅
Also I worked with 2 elements in X and 2 in Y and define a function in the case 1) and proved that there's an injective function defined by parts... but I don't know how to work in the case 2)

Comment: This is like asking if $a+b<ab$ for any $a,b\geq 2$.  To answer that, you might consider using the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Alternatively, if you so insist on defining an explicit injection, pick any $x_0\in X$ and $y_0\in Y$.  Consider a function $f~:~X\cup Y\to X\times Y$ given by $f(a) = \begin{cases}(a,y_0)&\text{if }a\in X\setminus Y\\(x_0,a)&\text{if }a\in Y\setminus X\\(a,a)&\text{if }a\in X\cap Y\end{cases}$ and adjust this slightly for the case of if $a$ is equal to either of $x_0$ or $y_0$.  (*This is where you'll use the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are sets with at least two elements*)

Comment: ohhh nice, it's similar the function that I defined when X∩Y=∅